# Getting `n` max or min values from column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have large dataframe. I want to find the row index of the `n` lowest element of some column. 
For ex : Consider following dataframe `df`

```
col_1 col_2 col_3
  1      2     3 
  -1     2     21 
  2      3     1
```

So `func(dataframe = df, column_name = col_1, n=2)` will return me

```
[1,2] #index of the rows
```

**NOTE : I want to avoid sorting the column.**

Comment: You question isn't super clear, but you could probably use `rank`.

Comment: Yeah I can use rank. But does rank internally uses sorting ?

Comment: Not sure you can do it without a sort of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question. I can think of (at least) four methods; all using base R solutions. Instead of working with a data frame, for simplicity I'm just creating a vector. If it works on a vector, just subset the data frame.

First some dummy data

```
x = runif(1e6)
```

Now the four methods (in order of speed)

```
## Using partial sorting
f = function(n){
  cut_off = sort(x, partial=n+1)[n+1]
  x[x < cut_off]
}

## Using a faster method of sorting; but doesn't work with partial
g = function(n){
  cut_off = sort(x, method="radix")[n+1]
  x[x < cut_off]
}

# Ordering
h = function(n) x[order(x)[1:n]]

#Ranking
i = function(n) x[rank(x) %in% 1:n]
```

Timings indicate, careful sorting seems optimal.

```
R> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(n), g(n), h(n),i(n), times = 4)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval  cld
 f(n)  112.8  116.0  122.1  122.6  128.1  130.2     4 a   
 g(n)  372.6  379.1  442.6  386.1  506.1  625.6     4  b  
 h(n) 1162.3 1196.0 1222.0 1238.4 1248.0 1248.8     4   c 
 i(n) 1414.9 1437.9 1489.1 1484.4 1540.3 1572.6     4    d
```

---

To work with data frames you would have something like:

```
cut_off = sort(df$col, partial=n+1)[n+1]
df[df$col < cut_off,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses ordering, but here is one approach.

```
set.seed(1)
nr    = 100
nc    = 10
n     = 5
ixCol = 1
input = matrix(runif(nr*nc),nrow = nr,ncol=nc)
input[head(order(input[,ixCol]),n),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and (for easier code) `magrittr`:

```
data(iris) # use iris dataset

library(dplyr); library(magrittr) # load packages

iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length %in% sort(Sepal.Length)[1:3])
```

This outputs the rows with the lowest 3 `Sepal.Length` values without sorting the data frame. In this case there are ties, so it outputs four rows.

To get the corresponding row names, you can use something like this:

```
rownames(subset(iris,
            Sepal.Length %in% sort(Sepal.Length)[1:3]))
```